# Multiple linear regression 2

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Suppose we have the multiple linear

How do I go about to do this? I know it should be a  but I have never done it when I have two predictors in the model. Would be grateful for any answer.

Comment: Do you have the data, or a printout of the regression procedure?

Comment: Yeah the data is:

Comment: The complication is that an extra delivery also adds extra distance. Time depends on both. Corr btw Dist and NrDel = .86. I ran the regression and both number of deliveries and distance provide useful information. For a meaningful result, you might ask how much extra time it takes to make one more delivery which adds an avg amt of time to the run. Or one more delivery that doesn't add distance. You might also just regress Time on Nr of Del alone: Time = 240 + 14.55(NrDel), and use the SE of the slope to test. Then I guess an extra delivery adds about 15 min. // Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Or is it (14.55-1)/SE of nrDel instead?

Comment: That might work. Try it and see if the answer makes sense. Not sure I have
a good enough mental picture of the data and the purpose to say for sure. Now that you have posted data, maybe some _regression expert_ will give advice.